# Modal bootstrap does not display correctly formatt text on modal-body

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

This is my modal-body

```
<div class="modal-body">
    root  2934  2.9  2.7 660824 222192 ?       Sl   07:57  12:02 skype
    root  3029  0.0  2.3 904676 189744 ?       Sl   07:57   0:20 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
</div>
```

but when I show it in Modal dialog bootstrap, it lost all formats and become only one single line like this:

```
root 2934 2.9 2.7 660824 222192 ? Sl 07:57 12:02 skype root 3029 0.0 2.3 904676 189744 ? Sl 07:57 0:20 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
```

How can I show it correctly? Thankyou.

Comment: This text is taken from databases (more than 100 record) so I can't use html to format for each record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wrap your content in a `pre` tag to persist formatting. Bare html won't maintain formatting otherwise unless you specify explicit unicodes

try this:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <pre>root  2934  2.9  2.7 660824 222192 ?       Sl   07:57  12:02 skype
    root  3029  0.0  2.3 904676 189744 ?       Sl   07:57   0:20 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
   </pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to show something like this you should use `pre` tag inside your `modalbox`